# Package missing on maven build

Tags: java, maven, m2e, travis-ci

I'm trying to run a JUnit test in Travis CI using Maven, but every attempt makes me face the same error:

```
[ERROR] \luiz.kill\Workspace\hawickjames\src\main\java\com\lzkill\main\CountElementaryCircuitsFromRFC.java:[3,24] error: package org.jgrapht.graph does not exist
```

I also see this when I use m2e to fire Maven, the dependencies don't even show up Eclipse as if the download was not processed.

It really looks like a javac problem. How can I make the download succeed and the compiler find the right jars?

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.lzkill</groupId>
<artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>...</name>
<description>...</description>
<url>...</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgrapht</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>protected</show>
                    <windowtitle>...</windowtitle>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: why did you specify dependencies under `<dependencyManagement>`

Comment: I just got it from some copy and pasting. It worked flawlessly by removing that tag, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify any dependencies only which version to use if you declare a dependency.
Remove the the dependencyManagement tags and you are set.

DependencyManagement helps you resolve version conflicts and is a good idea in a parent pom of multiple related projects. But it does not declare a dependency.

Comment: @Izkill, great. Could you mark this answer as "answers the question" to get it off the unanswered question list?